# Resolutions over Dedekind Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, dedekind-domain

I want to prove that if $R$ is a Dedekind Domain, then $\operatorname{Ext}_R^n(M,N)=0$, for $n \geq 2$.

Then, I have a question: There are any properties about projective or injective resolutions over Dedekind domains?

For exemple, if exists a projective resolution of lenght one for $M$ it is easy.

Any idea or reference?

Comment: Every finitely generated torsion free module over a Dedekind domain is projective.

Comment: Yes, but how it can help me?

Comment: If $M$ is a finitely generated module, take a surjection from a free module onto it. What can you say about the kernel?

Comment: Yes, but M is not finitely generated

Comment: @pmk you should know that the global dimension of a ring is determined by the projective dimensions of its finitely generated (even cyclic) modules.  One reference is https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00O2